# Are two ways of constructing $O(n)$ as a manifold equivalent?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, orthogonal-matrices

As well-known, $O(n)$ can be defined as a codimension $(n^{2}+n)/n$ submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n^{2}}$ via $A \mapsto A^{t}A$. Another way of constructing $O(n)$ as a manifold is construct smooth chart directly; by defining $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})^{\sharp}:= \{A \in M_{n}(\mathbb{R}): \det(I+A) \neq 0 \}$ and use $O(n)\cap M_{n}(\mathbb{R})^{\sharp}$ and its translation with Cayley transform $A \mapsto A^{\sharp}:=(I-A)(I+A)^{-1}$ as chart map.

My question is, these two ways of construction gives the same manifold structure?  How can I show these are the same manifold or not?

Comment: $\{ A \in M_n(\Bbb{R}), A^\top A=I\}$ is a subvariety of $M_n(\Bbb{R})$ to make it a submanifold you need more work (the group law of $O(n)$ might help). For the Caley transform you meant if 

$M^\top = -M$ then $(I+M)(I-M)^{-1}\in O(n)$ (proof : $(I+M)^\top (I+M)=I+M^\top M=(I-M)^\top (I-M)$) and it is a chart $\Bbb{R}^{ (n-1)n/2} \to O(n)$ around $I$ so left multiplying with $A\in O(n)$ we have a chart around $A$.

Comment: @reuns Yeah I know. My question is that those two construction gives the same manifold?

Comment: There is only one manifold here (only one chart : the ones given by shifts of Caley transform)